# Numpy: Shape mismatch error when putting 3d matrix into 4d matrix using boolean array indexing- python

Tags: python, numpy, variable-assignment, matrix-indexing

I have an error in my code and I have recreated it using the simplest example:

```
import numpy as np

zeros_4d = np.zeros((5,10,15,1))
zeros_3d = np.zeros((10,15,1))
ones_3d = zeros_3d + 1

bool_array = np.arange(0,15,1)>8

zeros_3d[:,9:,:] = ones_3d[:,9:,:] # This works fine
zeros_3d[:,bool_array,:] = ones_3d[:,bool_array,:] # This works fine

zeros_4d[0,:,9:,:] = ones_3d[:,9:,:] # This works fine

for i in np.arange(0,5,1):
    zeros_4d[0,i,bool_array,:] =  ones_3d[i,bool_array,:] # This works fine and does what I want

zeros_4d[0,:,bool_array,:] = ones_3d[:,bool_array,:] # This does not work
```

I get this error message: 'ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (10,6,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6,10,2)'

I do not understand why this is happening, is there anything that I can do to solve this problem or is looping the best way to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I suppose, the 3d array is smaller in my real code. For example the 4d array has a shape of (5,10,15,2) and the 3d array has a shape of (10,5,2), I would like to use boolean indexing to input the 3d array into the 4d array. I would like to do this without using a loop, as I think it should be possible if I do it correctly.

Comment: That `zeros_4d[0,:,bool_array,:]` indexing is a mix of basic and advanced, with a slice in the middle.  That's a special documented case, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing.  All the slice dimensions are shoved to the end, after the boolean index.

Comment: Thank you, @hpauji, that would have taken me forever to figure that out. First time posting here, but your comment seems good enough for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That `zeros_4d[0,:,bool_array,:]` indexing is a mix of basic and advanced, with a slice in the middle. That's a special documented case, docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/…. All the slice dimensions are shoved to the end, after the boolean index.

So with your 4d shape, and and a mixed index:

```
In [213]: arr = np.ones((5,10,15,2),int)                                                               
In [214]: arr[0,:, [1,2,3],:].shape                                                                    
Out[214]: (3, 10, 2)
```

We can get around this issue by first selecting the leading dimension:

```
In [216]: arr[0][:, [1,2,3],:].shape                                                                   
Out[216]: (10, 3, 2)

In [217]: arr[0][:, [1,2,3],:] = 2                                                                     
In [218]: arr                                                                                          
Out[218]: 
array([[[[1, 1],
         [2, 2],
         [2, 2],
         ...,
         [1, 1],
         [1, 1],
         [1, 1]],
        ...
```

Splitting an index during assignment can be a problem, if the first first index produces a copy rather than a view.  But here `arr[0]` is a view, so it's ok.